# React js nesting components/SearchBar component in Header

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have 2 components - a SearchBar component and a Header component.
I want to embed my SearchBar component in the Header component (like we see on Stackoverflow header above). So the header component must show throughtout the application but the Searchbar component should only embed after user logs in.

I have created a variable which has the Header(Header component) and it is nesting SearchBar into it. SearchBar will later perform a logic and return a table based on the search filters[search={changeSearchFilters}].

Issue - I'm able to render both individually, however, i'm not able to nest them and show together (stackoverflow header and the searchbar)

```
let headerBar=
    <Header> 
       <SearchBar search={changeSearchFilters}></SearchBar>  
    </Header>

  return (
    <div className="AppBody">
      {headerBar}
      <div className="anchor flexGrow" style={{ 'minHeight': '650px' }}>
        {Table1}
        {Table2}
        {Table3}
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you paste full code of how you are rendering Searchbar inside header, If possible a https://codesandbox.io/ codesandbox

Comment: I've tried to provide the relevant code above -
let headerBar=
    <Header> 
       <SearchBar search={changeSearchFilters}></SearchBar>  
    </Header>

and later i'm rendering the variable "headerBar" in return statement. Hope this helps.

Comment: How could we answer without knowing what `Header` and `SearchBar` is like?

Comment: Consider embedding `SearchBar` in `Header` via props like `<Header showSearchBar={true}/>`. And handle it in `Header`'s render method.

Comment: I am very new to react and aware that props needs to be used in this case (had even tried using it) but how do i render both of them together (SearchBar inside Header).